# Update nested object on create

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 3 models :

user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :profile, inverse_of: :user, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile
  has_many :bookings, inverse_of: :user, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :owner_bookings, foreign_key: 'owner_id', class_name: 'Booking'
end
```

profile.rb

```
class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  # mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
  belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :profile
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
end
```

booking.rb

```
class Booking < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :owner, class_name: :User
  belongs_to :poi
end
```

After a create booking, I would like to update the user profile (if some changes)

my form :

```
<%= simple_form_for [@poi.poitable, @booking] do |f| %>
  <%= f.simple_fields_for @user.profile do |profile| %>
    <%= profile.input :first_name,
                      input_html: { value: @user.profile.first_name } %>
    <%= profile.input :last_name, input_html: { value: @user.profile.last_name } %>
  <% end  %>
  <%= f.input :owner_id, input_html: { value: @poi.user.id } %>
  <%= f.input :poi_id, input_html: { value: @poi.id } %>
  <%= f.input :user_id, input_html: { value: @user.id } %>
  <%= f.submit %>  
<% end %>
```

booking_controller :

```
  def new
    @user = current_user
    @poi = Sleep.friendly.find(params[:sleep_id]).poi
    @booking = Booking.new
  end

  def create
    @user = current_user
    @poi = Sleep.friendly.find(params[:sleep_id]).poi
    @booking = Booking.new(booking_params)
    if @booking.save
      @booking.user.profile.update_attribute(booking_params[:user_profile_attributes])
  end

  private

  def booking_params
    params.require(:booking).permit(
      :poi_id,
      :owner_id,
      :user_id,
      user_profile_attributes: [:user_id, :first_name, :first_name],
    )
  end
```

booking_params return only :poi_id, :owner_id, user_id, how can I get user_profile params to update @user.profile ?

Comment: Are you sure `user_profile_attributes` is the right name? Can you post a sample `param` from the server log immediately after submit?

Comment: Try `@booking.user.profile.update_attributes` (plural)